# Need to add sum of amounts from a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

need to get the sum of amounts for the emp table based on the following conditions:

```
empid  yearquarter     type status   amount   orderdate
101      20151          1    A        3000     01-18-2015
101      20152          3    A        4000     05-09-2015
101      20152          4    A        5000     06-09-2015
101      20152          4    P        5000     06-09-2015
101      20152          1    A        7000     06-09-2015
101      20153          6    A        9000     09-11-2015
101      20153          7    A        10000    09-11-2015
101      20154          3    A        2000     12-12-2015
```

condition 1: need to add only status='A' and types other than (3,4) with respective to the yearquarter

condition 2: if in A particular year quarter there are only types(3,4) and status='A' we can add them

FROM THE ABOVE CONDITIONS

In 20151 we have only 1 record with type 1 
  WE NEED TO PICK 3000

In 20152 we have only 1 record with type:1 
  WE NEED TO PICK 7000 (we need to neglect all other records of different types)

In 20153 there are two records of types (6,7)
    WE NEED TO PICK 19000

IN 20154 THERE IS ONLY TYPE:3 RECORD WE NEED TO PICK 2000

```
so the total output needed is:31000
```

31000 should be displayed

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Stop rolling back to yelling

Comment: i am going with case statement for 2 different cases but for summing up the totals i am not able to

Comment: Why are you not able?   What error do you get?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for code (SQL) to sum the records based on few conditions. But there is no sample code to prove they have tried anything

Answer (score 0):

try this it should suffice your requirement

```
select  case when status ='A' AND type in (3,4) then SUM(amount) as amount 
          when status ='A' AND type not in (3,4) then yearquarter,amount end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated by the multiple layers of conditionality.  If I understand correctly:

```
select yearquarter,
       (case when sum(case when type not in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then sum(amount)
             else sum(case when type not in (3, 4) then amount else 0 end)
        end)
from t
where status = 'A'
group by yearquarter;
```

Comment: I have modified the question ... the query which you have shared is picking wrong values

Comment: how to add the yearquarter amounts into a single value